Lost network after upgrade
I got abit of an issue 
Got a report if anyone's interested.
Issue:
After upgrading to Fedora 40, I lost network connectivity on my system. DNS resolution fails, and I cannot ping or access any external sites, including using the browser.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Network Manager and SELinux:

Verified NetworkManager service is active.
Set SELinux to permissive mode.
Relabeled SELinux contexts.
Restarted NetworkManager and system.


DNS Configuration:

Checked and modified /etc/resolv.conf.
Added custom DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1) in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns.conf.
Ensured correct DNS settings with nmcli dev show.


Firewall and IP Routes:

Disabled firewall (firewalld).
Verified IP routes and default gateway settings.


Testing:

Attempted ping, traceroute, and wget without success.
Tested dnf for internet connectivity; failed to resolve hostnames.
Reinstalled NetworkManager without success.


Permissions:

Checked capabilities for /usr/bin/ping and /usr/bin/traceroute.

Attempted setting capabilities; no changes in behavior.

Ping results:
$ ping 10.3.14.1  
PING 10.3.14.1 (10.3.14.1) 56(84) bytes of data.  
From 10.3.14.179 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable  
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted  




Browser Behavior:

Browser does not work with either IP addresses or URLs.


Live OS and chroot Environment:

Network works fine when booted from a live USB.
chroot into the installed system from the live USB, and dnf update worked successfully.



Current Status:

NetworkManager: Active and running.
SELinux: Permissive.
DNS Configuration: Correct but no resolution.
Firewall: Disabled.
DNF: Unable to resolve hostnames.
IP Configuration: Correct IP and routes, unable to communicate with gateway.
Browser: Fails to load websites via both URLs and IP addresses.
Ping: Permission denied error.


Do you get the IP/mask/gateway from DHCP, or is it set statically? Do you see anything unexpected in like a duplicate adapter in nmtui? Can you ping your own IP or localhost? It really does look like what happens when the firewall blocks a ping, so double-check that firewalld is stopped, and that you don't have something else like nftables running. Make sure you don't have a route that specifies an old/missing interface ID or something

Are you able to ping your gateway? What exactly is 10.3.14.1?
